# How to ignore a repeated charcater in a line from a file using bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

I have a file with ***n*** number of lines which look like this:

```
a,b,c,,,,d
a,b,,,,c,d
a,,,,b,c,d
```

what I want to do is to delete the repeated commas from each line if there are repeated commas within that line. Therefore, the lines from my file should look like this:

```
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
```

I was trying to use grep or awk but I think I'm not really understanding those commands. I am new at bash and I'm kinda stuck so I would really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is probably the tool for this. Something like:

```
sed 's/,,*/,/g'
```

Which you can use with pipes in many ways.

The g option is global ( not m=multiple ) indicating that the phrase can occur more than once on the line - otherwise only the first on each line is modified.

Soon someone will come along and refer us to a duplicate. That's OK.

Answer (score 1):

this will be shorter

```
$ tr -s , <file

a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner to replace 1 or more occurrence of a comma with exactly 1 occurrence, multiple matches per line:

```
perl -pe 's/,+/,/g' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.